# "Крышной" или "крышный"?

Tags: орфография, орфоэпия

"Крышной" или "крышный" багажник автомобиля?

Answer (score 2):

«Русский орфографический словарь» РАН фиксирует написание *крышн**о**й*.

Answer (score 1):

А другой русский орфографический словарь фиксирует и написание *крышный*. Словосочетание "крышный багажник" употребляется гораздо чаще.

Comment: Смиренно надеюсь, что «Другой орфографический словарь» — это не то, что красуется на его обложке. :) А если серьёзно, что это за издание? Вы меня заинтересовали.